# Bigquery add missing rows

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, data-analysis

All

I want to add zero for missing year for animals. I have this result.

```
[
  {
    "value": 1,
    "animal": cat,
    "year": 2001
  },
  {
    "value": 2,
    "animal": cat,
    "year": 2002
  },
  {
    "value": 1,
    "animal": dog,
    "year": 2001
  },
  {
    "value": 1,
    "animal": dog,
    "year": 2002
  },
  {
    "value": 1,
    "animal": dog,
    "year": 2003
  },
]
```

But I want for animal which missing to add 0 value and the missing year

```
[
  {
    "value": 1,
    "animal": cat,
    "year": 2001
  },
  {
    "value": 2,
    "animal": cat,
    "year": 2002
  },
  {
    "value": 0,
    "animal": cat,
    "year": 2003
  },
  {
    "value": 1,
    "animal": dog,
    "year": 2001
  },
  {
    "value": 1,
    "animal": dog,
    "year": 2002
  },
  {
    "value": 1,
    "animal": dog,
    "year": 2003
  },
]
```

I have tried this for only one animal, but for two is not working. I don't know how to check if animal have all years. I was thinking to add default value, but how to add for every animal default years.

```
WITH test_table AS (
  SELECT *
FROM UNNEST (GENERATE_ARRAY(2001,2003)) AS YEAR
)
SELECT
  COALESCE(animals.value,0) as value,
  IFNULL(animals.animal,'cat') as animal
  test_table.year
FROM (
 SLECT
  year,
 FROM test_table
) as test_table
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
   value,
   animal,
   year
  FROM animals
  WHERE
   animal = 'cat'
) as animals
ON
test_table.year = animals.year
```

Comment: get distinct list of years, distinct list of animals cross join the two, then left join to your animals table and coalese 0 in for missing years on animals.  The issue is you need a unique list of animals for all years which can be accomplished with a cross join between the two distinct sets.